# Nvidia driver on virtual box (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: nvidia

My machine (Windows Host) has an NVIDIA driver GeForce GTX1060.

I have created a Virtual Box with a VM having Ubuntu 18.04 OS.

When checking the device drivers, this is the output I get:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc08sc80i00
vendor   : InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
model    : VirtualBox Guest Service
manual_install: True
driver   : virtualbox-guest-dkms - distro non-free
driver   : virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe - distro non-free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000015ADd00000405sv000015ADsd00000405bc03sc00i00
vendor   : VMware
model    : SVGA II Adapter
manual_install: True
driver   : open-vm-tools-desktop - distro free
```

I am trying to use TMIXT provided as a github on https://github.com/fadymedhat/TMIXT and an Nvidia driver is required. Is it possible to install on virtual box? Does the VM have access to Nvidia? Where can I find installation instructions for my case?

Comment: Look at https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5173/~/geforce-gpu-passthrough-for-windows-virtual-machine-%28beta%29  but looks like for a Windows VM.

Answer (score 5):

If an OS is running in a virtual machine then the graphics driver for the guest OS is virtual too. You cannot install or use an Nvidia graphics driver in a guest OS in either VirtualBox or VMware.

Comment: but can I use it from the VBox?

Comment: You cannot use it in either VirtualBox or VMware. What you are looking for is a dual boot alongside Windows.

Comment: One last question - can I install nvidia docker then on the VirtualBox? Or will I have issues?

Comment: Thanks...so I should try to run the git from my host? If it possible so that I can use the Nvidia docker right?

Comment: Before installing Nvidia Docker please check its hardware requirements to make sure that your computer supports it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102932/discussion-between-karel-and-katia).

Comment: This is not true. If you add PCI card (your Video card) to the virtual machine properties and launch with it, your card will show in lshw