# Can I Overclock my Ubuntu trough Windows 11 VM?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvidia-settings, overclocking

I need msi afterburner's Curve and Power limit settings desperately. is it Possible to overclock my RTX 2060 and RTX 3060 like that in ubuntu I couldn't find. That is why I am asking this. Please help!

Comment: A VM cannot see the actual hardware. A VM sees only the *imaginary* or *virtual* hardware that the Host VM application creates for the Guest to see. Trying to control real hardware only works if the Host VM application supports *passthrough* of that hardware.

Comment: Ok Thank you I have to reinstall windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia driver on virtual box (Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200966/nvidia-driver-on-virtual-box-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overclock hardware in a VM Guest OS.

In this situation, the Guest operating system is not running on your actual hardware: it is running on virtual hardware created and managed by the Host OS.